# Acentuação no terminal padrão do VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

Uso o VSCODE a muito tempo, e em todo esse tempo não consegui corrigir esse problema. A única resposta possivel que achei foi nesse post: https://plus.diolinux.com.br/t/visual-studio-code-nao-le-caracteres-acentuados-digitados-no-terminal-integrado/1490. Porém não resolveu meu problema. Até pq o autocomplete do vscode encontrar o terminal.integrated.env.osx e terminal.integrated.env.windows mas não o .linux como diz no post. Alguem saberia como corrigir?

Uso o vscode em inglês.

Comment: Aqui os acentos funcionam normalmente no terminal... http://prntscr.com/nx4e4l

Comment: Ajudou bastante

Comment: Talvez seja alguma config particular da sua máquina, aqui sempre funcionou normal... Fico feliz em ter ajudado 

Comment: opa @WillianFerrera conseguiu resolver esse problema? Utilizo o linux mint e aqui acontece a mesma coisa. O mais estranha é que no terminal do sistema a acentuação funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Não consegui cara, procurei em muitos lugares. Sim no sistema fica normal

Answer (score 1):

Eu estava tendo esse problema e aparentemente consegui resolver.

No VS Code vá em configurações, no canto superior direito tem o símbolo "{}".
Quando você clicar no ícone vai abrir para editar o arquivo "settings.json" onde você deve inserir a seguinte linha:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/K", "chcp 1252"]
```

Salve o arquivo, feche o VS Code e abra em seguida. No Terminal deve aparecer a mensagem "Página de código ativa: 1252".

Comment: Estou usando linux, não windows. Já havia mencionado acima.

Answer (score 1):

Depois de pesquisar bastante, descobri que o **Visual Studio Code** depende do `ibus` pra que a acentuação funcione no terminal integrado.

A melhor forma que eu encontrei de setar essa configuração foi usando os seguintes comandos:

Instalando o `ibus`:

```
sudo apt install ibus ibus-gtk3
```

Criando o arquivo de configuração:

```
cat <<EOF >ibus.dconf
[general]
preload-engines=['xkb:br::por']

[general/hotkey]
triggers=@as []

[panel]
show-icon-on-systray=false
EOF
```

Importando o arquivo de configuração no `dconf`:

```
dconf load /desktop/ibus/<ibus.dconf
```

Iniciando o `ibus` com a devida configuração:

```
im-config -n ibus
```

Ativando o `ibus` no **GNOME**(adapte para outros ambientes gráficos, se necessário):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('ibus', 'xkb:br::por')]"
```

[image]

Comment: Exatamente. Funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Demorei bastante pra descobrir essa solução, fico feliz em ter ajudado.