# Problema: Python 3.8 no Visual Studio Code no terminal Não aceita Acentos, Como Resolver ? Linux Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Estou com esse problema, já tentei mudar as configurações no visual Studio Code e nada, não achei nada na internet sobre isso, fora do terminal o acento apare normalmente agora na entrada de dados com input() não vai.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No terminal direto vai.
Dentro do Terminal no VS não vai.

Comment: E se executar direto no terminal do Linux, qual é o comportamento?

Comment: Normal, isso que é estranho

Comment: Não achei nada a respeito, já reinstalei e nada, no windows instalo normalmente e vai certinho.

Comment: Infelizmente não consegui reproduzir o problema. Estive pesquisando no repositório do VSCode e vi que muitos usuários estão com o mesmo problema e não é exclusivo do Ubuntu, também no Mac há usuários com a mesma dificuldade.

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição Augusto Vasques, espero que então logo se resolva pois desanima a gente querer tentar desenvolver algo e tem essas "pequenas coisas " que atrapalham.

Comment: Acabei de postar a solução pra esse problema [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/388702/acentua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-terminal-padr%C3%A3o-do-vscode/530147#530147).

Answer (score -1):

Também tive o mesmo problema. Não encontrei outra solução a não ser executar o Terminal a partir do Debug (F5). Desta forma aceita acentuação. No meu caso estava programando em Python.